# Can't pip install matplotlib after uninstalling PyQt4

Tags: python, matplotlib, fedora

After struggling with some things on my system (Fedora 25), I tried removing PyQt4, which did indeed uninstall it. When I went back to running a python script, I was told matplotlib was not installed. I did `pip install maplotlib` but I'm getting a huge error trace, which ends with `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object`.

I've tried the usual suspects, like making sure freetype and libpng are installed, and they are.

How can I fix this?

Comment: To clarify, do you get the traceback when installing matplotlib or running a python script? Also check your pip install command - in this post at least you have a typo `maplotlib` instead of `matplotlib`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is a *stack overflow*.(Definetly not this site...) It occurs because Python prevents the interpreter stack from growing larger than 
**sys.getrecursionlimit()**
. When you hit that limit you get the **RuntimeError** you mentioned.

Now, the usable resources of a program are limited. Each function call takes a certain amount of space on top of what is called the stack. If the maximum stack height is reached, you get a stack overflow error.
Try to convert the algorithm of your script from recursive to iterative.
Else,
You can increment the stack depth allowed - with this, deeper recursive calls will be possible, like this:

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(20000)
```

20000 is an example, try with different values. I had this problem onetime and I got away with changing the logic of my code.

Comment: Note that increasing the recursion limit is usually a terrible idea and can result in memory errors (due to the huge size of the stack). Only use for quick hacks or if you really know what you're doing. ;)